# email marked as spam even with DKIM, SPF and DMARC headers

Tags: email, spam-prevention

I've configured a `Postfix + Dovecot` email server. I took care of `SPF`, `DKIM`, `DMARC` and added appropriate headers to the message. I haven't used the machine for 2 years, so it can't be blacklisted from previous users. For reasons unknown to me, my email still gets marked as spam by gmail. This is the source of the mail, as seen by gmail client. I stripped away some of the very long unique ids and IPs, to make it more readable.

```
Delivered-To: targetemailaddress@gmail.com
Received: by IPv6_here with SMTP id s12csp565193ios;
        Fri, 1 Feb 2019 07:45:41 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: someuniquestring
X-Received: by 2002:a63:6c48:: with SMTP id h69mr34585542pgc.139.1549035941764;
        Fri, 01 Feb 2019 07:45:41 -0800 (PST)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1549035941; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=verylongstringhere==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=date:message-id:content-transfer-encoding:mime-version:reply-to
         :from:sender:subject:to:dkim-signature:dkim-filter;
        bh=somelongstring=;
        b=verylongstringhere2==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mycustomdomain.com header.s=201901 header.b=qCd3nM9G;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of support@mycustomdomain.com designates IPv6_here_2 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=support@mycustomdomain.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=mycustomdomain.com
Return-Path: <support@mycustomdomain.com>
Received: from mycustomdomain.com (mycustomdomain.com. [IPv6_here_2])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id k91si7726103pld.283.2019.02.01.07.45.41
        for <targetemailaddress@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Fri, 01 Feb 2019 07:45:41 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of support@mycustomdomain.com designates IPv6_here_2 as permitted sender) client-ip=IPv6_here_2;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mycustomdomain.com header.s=201901 header.b=qCd3nM9G;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of support@mycustomdomain.com designates IPv6_here_2 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=support@mycustomdomain.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=mycustomdomain.com
Received: by mycustomdomain.com (Postfix, from userid 48)
    id 743B95C468; Fri,  1 Feb 2019 16:46:12 +0100 (CET)
DKIM-Filter: OpenDKIM Filter v2.11.0 mycustomdomain.com 743B95C468
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=mycustomdomain.com;
    s=201901; t=1549035972;
    bh=somelongstring=;
    h=To:Subject:From:Reply-To:Date:From;
    b=vverylongstringhere3==
To: targetemailaddress@gmail.com
Subject: Update on the files
Sender: Support Team <support@mycustomdomain.com>
From: Support Team <support@mycustomdomain.com>
Reply-To: Support Team <support@mycustomdomain.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Message-Id: <20190201154612.743B95C468@mycustomdomain.com>
Date: Fri,  1 Feb 2019 16:46:12 +0100 (CET)

You start as a beginner and then you make it to the end.
```

I strongly feel that my problem has to do with inadequate headers. What headers should I add or change? I am not sure what else should I do..

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that email, Id imagine Giogle us objecting to the content - as a mail admin that looks spammy to me

```
 * Generic from
 * Generic subject with bad Englush Grammer
 * Short content with generic text and bag grammer
 * Subject line talks about file (trying to trick you into installing malware?)
```

It is unclear if this is a new domain, but sending stuff from a new domain is also more likely to be spam.

Comment: Thanks! It's not a new domain, but it never sent mail so far. So I should use: user account with a human name, use different test subject. I also tried with longer body, but was still thrown under the bus.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you claim you've never sent email from that server, it doesn't mean email wasn't sent from there, either in the past, through an open relay, a virus or rogue program, etc.

I would point you in 2 directions:

1. Check that the IP isn't blacklisted. Google for "**blacklist check**" and see what online tools are at your disposal
2. Check the spam rating of your email. Google for "**spam check email**". What you'll find is that there are services where you can send them a sample email, and minutes later a report will arrive at your inbox with a spam score assigned, as well as recommendations to improve your score.